# Assign function to every radio button

Tags: jquery, radio-button

I know it might be silly but I'm a newbie.
Se here is the thing:
I have two radio buttons and I want to get message depending on which you choose, but I'm receiving the same message for both of them and I don't know what I'm doing wrong:

```
<form method="post" action="demoform.asp">
      <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
      <legend>choose number</legend>
        <label for="one">number one</label>
        <input type="radio" id="number" name="1" value="1">
        <label for="second">number two</label>
        <input type="radio"  id="number" name="2" value="2">
      </fieldset>
       <p id="demo"></p>
        <input type="button" id="demo" onclick="myfunction()" >Click me</button>
    </form>
```

and script:

```
function myfunction() {
    var place = document.getElementById("number").value;
    var text;


    if (place === "1") {
        text = "Spot Good job!";


    } else if (place === "2" ) {
        text = " close enough.";
            } 
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
}
```

Comment: To start with IDs **must** be unique

Comment: And typically radio element share a common name attribute.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your radio buttons to work as real radio buttons, then they should have the same `name` attribute. You also cannot have multiple elements with the same `id` attribute. Lastly, your HTML has a syntax error for the button.

```js
function myfunction() {
    var place = document.querySelector('input[name="number"]:checked');
    var text;

    if (!place) {
        text = "Select a radio option";
    } else if (place.value === "1") {
        text = "Spot Good job!";
    } else if (place.value === "2" ) {
        text = " close enough.";
    } 
  
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
}
```

```html
<form method="post" action="demoform.asp">
      <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
        <legend>choose number</legend>
        <label for="number_1">number one</label>
        <input type="radio" id="number_1" name="number" value="1">
        <label for="number_2">number two</label>
        <input type="radio"  id="number_2" name="number" value="2">
      </fieldset>
      
      <p id="demo"></p>

      <button type="button" id="demo" onclick="myfunction()" >Click me</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your radio buttons must have the same name, but unique IDs.
You can use

```
<label for="one">number one</label>
<input type="radio" id="n1" name="number" value="1">
<label for="second">number two</label>
<input type="radio"  id="n2" name="number" value="2">
<input type="button" id="demo" onclick="myfunction()" >Click me</button>
```

using javascript:

```
var text;
if(document.getElementById("n1").checked)
    text = "Spot Good job!";
if(document.getElementById("n2").checked)
    text = " close enough.";
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
```

Answer (score 0):

The value of your for attribute of the label tags or elements should match the value of the id attribute of the input element or tags...also note that best practice is to nest the input element in the label elements and also use the Value attribute, the value attribute needs to be set to something to identify the option.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29896648)